# How to convert model to migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a bit confused by this. On creating a model, I always thought that this would produce a migration which then gets pushed into a database. 
So when I type

rails g model Userss name:string email:string group:integer

in the model I get:

```
class Userss < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and in the migration (`20150619151857_create_usersses.rb`)I get:

```
class CreateUsersses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :usersses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :group

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

however, if I type `rails g model Userss name:string email:string group:integer --migration=false`

I get the same model, but then when I run a migration as 
`rails g migration userss`, I get a file which is not called `....create_userss.rb`, but is called `20150619152316_userss.rb` and it contains:

```
class Userss < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

so why is there a difference in the migration file?

Comment: It is because you given `rails g migration userss`

Comment: sure but doesnt the migration come from my definition in the model?

Comment: if it doesnt then wwhats the point of the model?

Comment: The command `rails g migration userss` is not a valid one, so its just create an empty migration file.

Comment: so whats the point of defining associations in the model if they just get ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you confused about how the rails migration generators work. They actually don't care at all about your models.

When you run:

```
rails g model user name:string
```

Rails just runs the migration generator for you:

```
rails g migration CreateUsers name:string
```

Rails can figure out from the naming of the migration what kind of migration to generate. `CreateUsers name:string` will obviously create a create table migration.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end
```

`AddFooToUsers foo:int` will create a migration to alter `users`:

```
class AddFooToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :foo, :int
  end
end
```

Rails does not really care if you use camelcase or snakecase for the migration name in the generator `add_fields_to_users` or `AddFieldsToUsers` give the same result.

Also the Rails convention is to use the singular form for model names (User, Fruit, Car etc) this is very important since it lets rails automatically figure out the connection between controllers and models.

Even more important is that you don't misspell common english words like users since it will confuse every poor sod who has to maintain your code.

Comment: OK that's very useful. However I remain confused about the point of the model in that case. Is it therefore just a layer to query the database. What's the point of writing associations into the model such as has_many if this then doesn't become part of a migration? Sounds like I'm missing something fundamental

Comment: Models are as you have surmised a layer in the application which is used to represent data in MVC applications. They both encapsulate the data and provide what is called the business logic. Model provide a layer of abstraction over using raw SQL which make it possible to change RBDMS systems and even to change to a "nosql" database like Mongoid without rewriting the entire application. This article explains it very well but is a bit dated http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've read it but it still doesn't explain why I would bother writing the associations in the model. I understand why I'd do it in the migration as I'm altering database structure but why in the model?

Comment: Because just having a `something_id` on your database tables is not going to do anything. If you actually want to link different models together (`user.tweets`) you need to tells rails what the relation is. There is just no way it can figure out all the nuances and variations of relations just by looking at the schema. Rails is not unique in this regard, this how most ORM systems work. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: OK. Got it I think. SO you have to define new relationships in the migration and also in the model seperately

Comment: Exactly. You actually create the database columns, foreign keys and indices you need using migration, not the actual relations. Relational databases are kind of stupid; they have joins, primary and foreign but not any a higher level understanding of the relations between the tables.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a migration that will add columns to the Userss table, do this:

```
rails g migration add_fields_to_userss name:string email:string group:integer
```

That will create a migration to add columns to an existing table. If you don't add the `_to_userss` at the end then it will just create a generic migration file for you.

`rails g model Userss name:string ...`
will create a migration that, when run, will create the table Userss with the specified columns.

`rails g migration blah_blah_blah_to_userss name:string ...` will create a migration that only adds columns and references to the existing table Userss.

Comment: but what if I want to migrate an existing model

Comment: That's what this (above) does; the `_to_userss` part tells rails to add columns to the `Userss` table instead of trying to generate a new `Userss` table.